# В редакторе макетов отображается пустой макет

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно заметить, что все элементы сжимаются в правом верхнем углу макета

Код макета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alim.groupnotes"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Build.gradle(Project: MyProject)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: А если `build` сделать или просто приложение запустить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на устройстве все отображается корректно, но в редакторе макетов никаких изменений

Comment: Это со всей разметкой так или только с этой или во всех проектах, не только в этом?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Это уже второй проект. В первом было две разметки и ни одна из них не отображалась

Comment: А вот справа вверху у вас красный кружок - там что-то написано?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Две одинаковые ошибки "Render problem. Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error."

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Это может быть из-за того, что нахожусь я в Крыму, который попадает под санкции?

Comment: Вряд ли из-за этого) Попробуйте обновить библиотеки, если они у вас не последние. [Тут сказано](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44449275/3212712) что такое из-за бага определённой версии оных может быть. Если не поможет .- покажите оба `build.gradle` файла проекта

Comment: @АлимАсанов, а попробуйте убрать `tools:context=".Main"` - так отображается контент?

Comment: установите версию андроид ниже на экране превю. иногда такое мне помогает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб библиотеки последние, оба файла gradle прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: @Ksenia Убрал, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych попробовал каждую версию от 17 и выше

Comment: @АлимАсанов, [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786934/3212712) ещё пишут, что может помочь снижение до `28.0.0-alpha1` вместо `3` и `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это тоже не помогло. Но я нашел решение. Спасибо большое за вашу помощь

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел решение [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio/45225820). В файле 'styles.xml' заменил эту строчку:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

на эту:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

Теперь все отображается так, как должно.

Comment: наверное в файле styles.xml, а не strings.xml, да? Все же это скорее костыль, чем решение (менять тему чтобы отображалось правильно в визуальном редакторе, хотя приложение будет работать все же на устройстве, в котором и с нужной темой проблем нет). Думаю к релизу 28 версии саппорт библиотек все поправят и можно будет использовать ту тему, которая нужна, а не которая не глючит

Comment: @pavlofff Да styles.xml, сделал ошибку) сейчас исправлю. Вы совершенно правы, я сразу и не подумал об этом - это не полноценное решение